# Проблемы с position:fixed

Tags: html, css

Меню закреплено наверху, но при прокрутке страницы, некоторые элементы залезают поверх меню.

```css
nav {
    font-family: AA;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 11%;
    background-color: azure;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
    <a href="#top">Головна</a> 
    <a href="#services">Послуги</a> 
    <a href="#galery">Ескізи</a>
    <a href="#work">Роботи</a>
    <a href="#contact">Контакти</a>
</nav>
```

Поверх заходят все элементы с `positon: absolute`, `relative`...
Использовал даже `position: relative` & `z-index 1`.

Comment: можно увеличить z-index для закреплённого меню, например (значение 1000000 вполне подойдёт для теста)

Comment: не помогает тестил

Comment: извиняюсь) z-index: 1000; я забил про такое свойство)

Comment: Я ничего не имею против граждан Украины, но считаю, что на данном ресурсе неприемлемо писать на украинском языке. Это все-таки ru. а не ua. Конечно, я понимаю суть вопроса, но совершенно неудобно читать этот текст, да и вопрос оформлен не совсем правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте для `nav { z-index: 9999; }`и проверьте, что бы у элементов, которые "налазят" на меню не был задан `z-index` больше, чем у `nav`.

Comment: уже разобрался)) но всеравно спасибо)

Comment: Будь ласка! ; )